# Unupvote removes rep from the daily cap, but later upvotes don't add rep again

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, upvotes, daily-reputation-limit

Yesterday, I hit the rep cap around 11:00 UTC. My question kept being upvoted. Then I got the following events:

```
    21:03   upvote
+2  21:02   upvote   
-5  21:02   unupvote     
-2  20:50   downvote
    ...
    11:09   upvote
+5  11:00   upvote
```

I ended up with 195 upvote rep (+15 for an accepted answer) despite having more than 130 upvotes on a single question for today only. My reputation tab also indicates: +202/-7 for yesterday, and my reputation change widget (the one that shows the green +X in the nav bar) also shows a grand total of 210 rep gained for yesterday.

At midnight, my rep was 12203. Current rep and recent upvotes confirms that at midnight I was a 12203. So I checked https://stackoverflow.com/reputation and there, it's written that at midnight, I should have been at 12208. So my website rep and my computed rep on https://stackoverflow.com/reputation differ by 5, exactly the unupvote.

So I believe there's something off in regards to the daily rep cap and the upvote / unupvote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The upvote that was retracted occurred on a previous day - it *had* to, because if it had occurred on the *same* day, it would have been hidden entirely from your history because we collapsed upvote/unupvote pairs that occur same-day.

You lost 5 reputation from the day where the upvote originally occurred. But the system doesn't automatically recalculate things that affect days past. It removes the amount of reputation that was assigned to that vote and does nothing else.

*At some point* when your profile triggers a full recalculation, it will look at that previous day and see that you had other votes that could cover the reputation that was lost from the retracted vote, and it will assign the +5 to the next qualifying vote of that day. Generally, any deletion or undeletion event on one of your posts will schedule you for a reputation recalc, and it'll occur the next time the system processes them.

Comment: Okay, that seems clear. Unexpected, but sound. Also, it seems that I've already caught up the upvote as I now have an extra +5 for another day.